# Re-use azure mobile service client across activities

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I've been working with Azure Mobile Services and Xamarin Android and I'm currently stumped on how to re-use a mobile service client. Every Xamarin Android example I've seen uses a single activity that creates a new reference to a client. I would like to create a reference to the client once and re-use it across multiple activities.

I've followed [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-android-get-started-users/) so far but am kind of stumped on how to make this work for multiple activities. I really don't want to keep creating new instances of this client throughout the app.

One motivation for doing this is I don't want to have to keep re-authenticating every time I make a new client reference. Ideally I would create the client once, authenticate, and then re-use that client throughout my activities.

I'm out of my element on this one as I have little experience working with these tools, so any pointers on how to do this (or even reasons NOT to do this and how to do it correctly) are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you application you can create a static class like this

```html
   public static class AzureMobileService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="AzureMobileService"/> class. 
        /// </summary>
        static AzureMobileService()
        {

            Instance = new MobileServiceClient("http://<your url>.azure-mobile.net/", "< you key>")
            {
                SerializerSettings = new MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    CamelCasePropertyNames = true
                }
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The customers service.
        /// </value>
        public static MobileServiceClient Instance { get; set; }
    }
```

And each time you need it you should use

```html
AzureMobileService.Instance
```

this way your client instance will be the same for the application no matter which page you are :)

Answer (score 0):

A different method instead of using a static class is to use an `Application` class. The `Application` class is the root of the app and stays in memory throughout the app's life cycle.

```
[Application]
public class AppInitializer : Application
{
    private static Context _appContext;

    public MobileServiceClient ServiceClient { get; set; }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        ServiceClient = new MobileServiceClient("http://<your url>.azure-mobile.net/", "< you key>")
        {
            SerializerSettings = new MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                CamelCasePropertyNames = true
            }
        };
    }

    public static Context GetContext()
    {
        return _appContext;
    }
}
```

Then inside an activity you can use it like this:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var appState = (AppInitializer) ApplicationContext;

        //appState.ServiceClient
    }
}
```